# how to archive download multiple files from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

Actually i got the zipfile. But i did't need total files from the table.i want to selected userid files... I try to code bellow, i used php and mysql.

```
    <?php

    function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
            exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
        }

        foreach($file_names as $files)
        {
            $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);
            //echo $file_path.$files,$files."<br />";
        }
        $zip->close();
        header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); 
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        header("Expires: 0"); 
        readfile("$archive_file_name");
        exit;
    }
    require_once("config.php");
    $cqurfetch=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums where user_id='$user_id' and accept='1'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cqurfetch))
    {
       $file_names[] = $row['user_album_images'];
    }
       $archive_file_name=time().'.gallery.zip';
       $file_path="/uploads/";
       zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);
?>
```

Comment: $file_names array what you get in that? all files are only $user_id files.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question

Comment: i want to only $user_id files,not all files

Comment: ok sure..can you give me one example path of $user_id files.

Comment: have get any answers for your question.

Answer (score 1):

After Many trails i have got one answer for your question.

Only **'user_id'** files are zipped and stored in that zip folder.

**Example:-**

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

  $user_id = 49 ;  //Just For your reference
  $accept = 1 ;     //Just For your reference

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM albums where user_id='$user_id' and accept='$accept'";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $array[] = $row["user_album_images"];
     echo "user_album_images: " .$row["user_album_images"]. "<br>"; //This is also just for your reference 
     }
    }
    else{
    echo "fail"; 
    }

 $file= "/uploads/gallery.zip"; //Zip file path
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 echo "*****zip started.*****\n";   
  if ($zip->open($file, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
{  
     $zip->addFile("/".$value);
            }
     $zip->close();
     echo '^^^^^^Zip ended^^^^^^';
  }
?>
```

I have tested this code in my local system,this is working as like your requirement.

Hope this helps